# How do I rename the android package name?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Pressing Shift+F6 seems only to rename the last directory.
**For example**, in the project `com.example.test` it will offer to rename test only. The same applies if I navigate to package name in `.java` or Manifest file and press Shift+F6.

So is there a way to rename the package?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can do this:

1. Change the package name manually in the manifest file.
2. Click on your `R.java` class and the press <kbd>F6</kbd> (**Refactor->Move...**). It will allow you to move the class to another package, and all references to that class will be updated.

Comment: It still compiles as com.old_name.test. Can you help with this?

Comment: It shouldn't if you change the package name in the manifest. Just tried that and it worked fine.

Comment: you should change the package name in the manifest

Comment: Worked for me (using Android Studio 0..9.1) but in reverse order. First moved the R.java class to the new package. Second step was to delete duplicate R.java (it appeared in source folder in the new package). And lastly, manually changed the package name in manifest file.

Comment: FWIW, if you're using Android Studio, you can just do 'move' on the package (*not* rename) and choose "move 'x.y.z' to another package". No other steps required.

Comment: all my imports in activities classes and the previous package name

Comment: Refer to this question - best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: I am new in Android. where can i find this R.java ?

Answer (score 165):

The best way to solve this is going to the AndroidManifest.xml: `package="com.foocomp.fooapp`:

- Set the cursor on *"foocomp"*
- Press <kbd>Shift+F6</kbd>
- *Rename Package* to whatever you want
- Repeat for *"fooapp*".

Works for me.

Also, replace in Path in Whole Project as it didn't change everything. Then Clean, Rebuild and it works --> In Android Studio / IntelliJ you should unmark "Compact Empty Middle Packages"

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct

Comment: Exactly, this did the thing. Also Replace in Path in WHole Project as it didn't change everythin. Then Clean, Rebuild and it works

Comment: also change the applicationId attribute in app/build.gradle file

Comment: "set the cursor to". not sure what that means i put the cursor infront of the first part and it will only refactor the first part.

Comment: I edited / improved the first part of this answer as it worked best for me (easiest way)

Comment: If you need to change "com" part delete all build files manually. Then press shift+F6 then refrator it. Change the applicationId attribute in app/build.gradle file.

Comment: You may have to manually change package name in `build.gradle` file as well.

Comment: You also have to press Do refactor in the very bottom of Android Studio. Only after that, the correct text gets renamed

Comment: What does "Also, replace in Path in Whole Project as it didn't change everything." mean?

Answer (score 34):

Eclipse: 
Right click on the project > Android tools > Rename application package.

As simple as that...

[image]

In Android Studio:
open the build.gradle file > rename the applicationId under defaultConfig > synchronize

Comment: but it doesnt rename the package after sync, do i have to rename manually everything else, the packages with java files, also in mainfest?

Comment: In Android Studio, this does not update the package name in the manifest

Comment: to elaborate on on what MarkCarter said, you need to change packagename, not application ID.  check out http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 30):

1. Goto your AndroidManifest.xml.
2. place your cursor in the package name like shown below **don't select it just place it.**

[image: Just place your cursor on it]

3. Then press `shift+F6` you will get a popup window as shown below select 
   **Rename package**.

[image]

4. Enter your new name and select **Refactor**.
   (Note since my cursor is on "something" only something is renamed.)

That's it done.

Answer (score 14):

I found another solution for renaming a package in the entire project:

1. Open a file in the package.
2. IntelliJ displays the breadcrumbs of the file, above the opened file.
3. On the package you want renamed: Right click > Refactor > Rename.

This renames the package/directory throughout the entire project.

Comment: This one worked for me, thanks. With one addition: I had to rename the references in files in the "res" folder manually.

Comment: works for me, with the need to change the package name inside manifest file

Comment: This worked like charm even in Android Studio. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Deselect Hide Empty Middle Packages in Project Explorer Windows settings menu than you will be able to refactor each directory

Answer (score 11):

Lets address the two use cases

**Rename a package name  or Trim a package **

*com.mycompany.mystupidapplicationname* to *com.mycompany.brandname*

or

*com.someothercompany.mystupidapplicationname* to *com.someothercompany.mystupidapplicationname*

or

*com.someothercompany.mystupidapplicationname* to 
*someothercompany.brandname*

1. Select Package in the drop down in Android Studio

[image: Select package in dropdown]

2. Right click on the package which contains your MainActivity and refractor it

[image]

3. Select Rename Package and everything will work like a charm

But this will only rename the last part of package name

4. To rename the first or second part of package name . Create a new dummy file in the part of package which you want to rename. the file will be created inside mycompany.com.myapplicationame.  Then move the file inside mycompany(right click => move) to make mycompany appear in tree view. This will make that part part of the tree view and will you help you to do a right click and rename that part.

[image]

5. Delete the dummy file
6. To Trim a package , simply right click and move the package part inside its grand parent

Answer (score 8):

I found a good work around for this problem. Taking the example mentioned in the question, following are the steps for changing the package name from `com.example.test` to `com.example2.test` :

1. create a temporary directory, say `temp` inside the directory `example` (alongside directory `test`).
2. Go back to the Intellij project, select the folder `com.example` and Click `Shift + F6`. Now it offers to rename the text `example`. Here you can enter the new text you want and IntelliJ will do the rest for you.
3. Delete the temporary directory `temp` from the file system.

This idea can be used to refactor any part of the package name.

Good luck!!

Comment: Does this rename `Manifest` package name as well? Does this way rename custom elements like `com.example.test.mycoolbutton`?

Comment: It does rename everything in "IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 11".

Comment: You can simply ask IntelliJ not to `Compact Empty Middle Packages` (option in the Project hierarchy view), then proceed to renaming each directory. No need to create temporary directories :)

Answer (score 5):

This modification needs three steps :

1. Change the package name in the manifest
2. Refactor the name of your package with right click -> refactor -> rename in the tree view, then Android studio will display a window, select "rename package"
3. Change manually the application Id in the build.gradle file :
   android / defaultconfig / application ID

Then clean / rebuild the project

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately all above didn't work for me. After having lots of trials,
What worked for me in Android Studio:

1. do a 'move' on the package to a new package name you want.(right
   click on package and select Refactor -> Move)
   If Refactor -> Move didn't work for you, then create a package with the name               you want and move manually in the existing package to the new one, and then delete the old empty package.
2. Change package name in manifest (manually)
3. Have a replace for the old package name with the new package name
   globally (in the full path by going to Edit -> Find -> Replace In
   Path)

Comment: Only this answer worked in my case, where I have to remove a folder itself from the package name

ex: to change from **com.company.name.customer** to **com.company.name**

Answer (score 4):

What I did was the following :

I simply created the package with the desired name , in the src folder , next to the current package with current name.

I dragged all contents of current package to new package , intellij popped a dialog box asking me if I want to refactor inside package references and project references to new package , I clicked 'yes' and TA-DAAA , worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 1.1, the simplest way is to open your project `manifest file`, then point to each part of the `package name` that you want to change it and press 
 <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> , then choose `rename package` and write the new name in the dialog box. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers even the most voted answers didn't do the job properly, they seem to work and the builds work however, a closer look at the file structure and references will show you that not much was done. IntelliJ actually does this whole process automatically.

1) Go to Project Tab and make sure Packages is the active Tab in the drop down like so:

[image: Select Packages in the drop down]

find your com.example package (note test as in com.example.test is not there) right-click and choose Refactor->Rename...

It will issue a warning that multiple directories... (which is actually the desired effect), click on Rename package.

Input the new package name and Refactor...

It will do searches and show you refactoring results.

Click on the Do Refactor button and it will do everything and even rename the folders and files involved... every reference is corrected to this new name.

2) Then Finally change the AndroidManifest.xml file

:)

Comment: One Step Missed, Change the manually package name in Gradle file. :)

Comment: This seems a good solution but you cannot change the prefix "com.example.". You may change only the suffix "test" in this example. And this is not sufficient to most developers.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers even the most voted answers didn't do the job properly, they seem to work and the builds work however, a closer look at the file structure and references will show you that not much was done. IntelliJ actually does this whole process automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by changing the directory name manually from the command line. Intellij then recognized the new package name automatically. I then had to do a search and replace for the package name in each file that imported it. This seems like an ugly workaround, but Intellij seemed unwilling to change the package name otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was the following

1. Change manifest.
2. Close androidStudio
3. Open folder with Windows Explorer. Change folder names.
4. Open androidStudio, and do a search and replace.

Done!

Comment: This must be the accepted answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename full android package, this is the best way to do that:

1. Mark as checked - Comapct Emty Middle Packages
2. Right click on the packcage you want to change, and then
   Refactor->Rename->Rename all

You can find video tutorial on this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-rITYZQj0A

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Cristian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6600360/3036759) above, I had to do two more steps to get it working correctly. I will sum all of it here:

1. Change the package name manually in the manifest file.
2. Click on your `R.java` class and the press `F6` (Refactor->Move...). It will allow you to move the class to another package, and all references to that class will be updated.
3. Change manually the application Id in the `build.gradle` file : android / defaultconfig / application ID [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988188/3036759).
4. Create a new package with the desired name by right clicking on the java folder -> new -> package and select and drag all your classes to the new package. Android Studio will refactor the package name everywhere [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637004/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: I changed src subfolder names, manifest file, activity headers and run/debug configuration. And still got building errors. If your project is not so big, just create a new project, copy-paste old files and change package names in headers of .java files and android manifest.

Solution 2: Inside IntelliJ 12, goto **someFile.java** and find your old package name

```
package com.myself.project2
```

click to which word that you want to change. Press <kbd>Shift+F6</kbd>.
Dialog comes, type new name.

Then goto Run/Edit configurations. Inside Launch radio button change package name to new one. It should work.

Other renaming options of IntelliJ are: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/rename-refactorings.html

Answer (score 0):

**Super simple** approach:

1. **Find** `R.java` in the build/generated directory
2. **Create** new package directories, again under build/generated/etc
3. **Move** `R.java` to the newly created package.
4. A dialog will appear. Choose to **refactor** the existing code with the new package name.
5. **Clean** and **Rebuild**

Done!