# Fully change package name including company domain

Tags: android, android-studio, android-package-managers

Let's suppose this is the package name:
`package com.company.name`. How do I change `company`?

P.S. I saw how to change `name` but not `company`. 
I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: i started to make a project, and i need to change the `company` word with another, because this project is for a company. and why use delete key?? where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: Just create a new package, then select classes you want to move then drag-and-drop it into new created package, then refactor, this work for me

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this:

Change the package name manually in the manifest file.
Click on your R.java class and the press F6 (Refactor->Move...). It will allow you to move the class to other package, and all references to that class will be updated.

reference: [How do I rename the android package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/rename-full-android-package-name)

Answer (score 60):

**current package : *com.company.name***

**New   package : *com.mycomapny.name***

Steps:
1) Suppose you are at this screen which is shown below.

[image]

2) Open project pane and click on settings icon.

3) Deselect Compact Empty Middle Packages.

4) Then your package is now broken into individual parts as shown below .

5) right click on "company" select Refactor -> select rename ->rename directory.

[image]

6) Now your "company" has been changed to new "mycomapny" and changes were     reflected as shown in below figure.

[image]

7) Now change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml file .

[image]

8) Open app level build.gradle and change package name .

[image]

9) you will get errors as Cannot resolve symbol "R" .

10) Remove line which gives this error and studio will import new R file  automatically.

11) If you have multiple files then use find and replace option by pressing " Cntrl+Shift+R "

Or  " Select Edit->Find->Replace in path.."

[image]

12) select Replace All.

Comment: good answer, but why would you only rename the directory? this is why you get all these issues with unresolved symbol R, etc. I followed your instructions but renamed the package rather than the directory. then I didn't have to change the manifest, R references etc.

Comment: Probably worth saying that I tried a few of these ways and none of them were totally straight forward. I had to manually add a few folders to get the directories right after the rename. It's working now though, so read a few of the approaches and anticipate some hiccups.

Answer (score 35):

This worked for me, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637004/127434

> Another good method is: First create a new package with the desired
>   name by right clicking on the java folder -> new -> package.
>
> Then, select and drag all your classes to the new package.
>   AndroidStudio will refactor the package name everywhere.
>
> Finally, delete the old package.

Comment: This worked partially for me, but it didn't fix the "import com.company.foo" statements. I was able to do the latter with a global replace in the src/ directory.

Answer (score 17):

**In Android Studio, you can do like this:**

For example, if you want to change com.example.app to iu.awesome.game, then:

1. In your Project pane, click on the little gear icon ( [image] )
2. Uncheck / De-select the Compact Empty Middle Packages option
   [image]
3. Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories
4. Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

   - Right-click it
   - Select Refactor
   - Click on Rename
   - In the Pop-up dialog, click on Rename Package instead of Rename
     Directory
   - Enter the new name and hit Refactor
   - Click Do Refactor in the bottom
   - Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
   - Note: When renaming com in Android Studio, it might give a warning.
     In such case, select Rename All[image]

     5. Now open your Gradle Build File (build.gradle - Usually app or mobile). Update the applicationId in the defaultConfig to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:[image]
     6. You may need to change the package= attribute in your manifest.
     7. Clean and Rebuild.
     8. Done! Anyway, Android Studio needs to make this process a little simpler.

Answer (score 9):

@Luch Filip's solution works well if you just want to rename the App package.  In my case, I also want to rename the source package too, so as not to confuse things.

Only 2 steps are needed:

1. Click on your source folder e.g. `com.company.example` > **Shift + F6** (Refactor->Rename...) >  **Rename Package** > enter your desired name.
2. Go to your AndroidManifest.xml, click on your package name > **Shift + F6** (Refactor->Rename...) > enter same name as above.

Step 1 will automatically rename your R.java folder, and you can build straight away.

Comment: All good, except I get "IOException: cannot rename (...)" for the main source folder. Simple project, just opened.

Comment: I use Android studio 2.1.1 . My specific For example, at first, I have `info.apachehive.cardview`, I want have `net.vyhn.cardview`. **Step 1.** Choose tree view source code. **Step 2.** Click `apachehive`, press Shift+F6 Refactor\Rename to `vyhn`. **Step 3.** Click `info` folder, press Shift+F6 Refactor\Rename to `net`. File `AndroidManifest.xml` automatically change. Then I run debug, my application works well.

Answer (score 5):

Four steps are given below:

1. Click on app folder below:

[image]

*com.new25.impro. press Shift + F6 {Refactor->Rename...}* to rename the package and press `refactor`.

2. After that one, see the android monitor. That show change everywhere that packagename. Click `refactor`.
3. Go to module `app:change` the application id for you like that name put it. and click `sync now`.
4. Now you can change the package name to what you like.

Answer (score 4):

I have read almost all the answers. But I think one is missing. Sometimes I may be wrong.
I have used the below method and it's working.

[3 Methods to change package name in Android Studio](https://androidride.com/how-to-change-rename-android-app-package-name-android-studio/)

1. **Select** your **package** and **Right-click**, **Refactor -> Move**.
2. Choose Move package from **"your package"** to **another package** and click Ok.
3. A new dialog appears, says Multiple directories correspond to package "your package" and click **Yes**.
4. Enter the new package name except for the last level or last name. Means If you want to rename package name to "info.xyz.yourapplication". Then type down "info.xyz" only leave "yourapplication".
5. Click **Refactor**.
6. A new dialog, **Package info.xyz** does not exist. Do you want to create it?. Click on **Yes**.
7. Click **Do refactor**.
8. Right-click on the new package to change the last name. **Refactor-> Rename**.
9. **Rename package**
10. type new name and click **Do refactor**.
11. Delete all old package directories.
12. Change ApplicationId in build.gradle file and click on **sync now**

Comment: For me, this is the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your company domain / package name is very long, it is more tricky.

This was the missing link for me. You need to select Project files -> settings -> then uncheck 'compact empty middle classes.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open the project folder in Android Studio.
2) Select app folder -> Right click, and select **refactor**.
3) Click on move. It will ask to which package name type you own full   package name and it will ask to create a new package yes create new automatically it ask for `gradle` to `sync`.

Comment: May be you can add some screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

To rename the package name in Android studio, Click on the setting icon in the project section and untick the Compact empty Middle Packages, after that the package will split into multiple folder names, then right click on the folder you need to change the name, click on refactor-> Rename-> Type the name you want to change in -> Refactor -> Refactor Directory, then import R.java file in the whole project. Working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this would be to rename the root app folder from `com.example.MyApp` to `com.newcompanyname.MyNewAppName` and then replace all occurrences of the old path to the new path in whatever IDE you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for renaming a package in the entire project:

Open a file in the package.
IntelliJ displays the breadcrumbs of the file, above the opened file.
On the package you want renamed: Right click > Refactor > Rename.
This renames the package/directory throughout the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem & here is how I solved :-

I want to change package name ***np.com.shivakrstha.userlog*** to ***np.edu.khec.userlog***

I selected ***shivakrstha*** and I pressed **Shift + F6** for Rename Refract and renamed to ***khec***.

Finally, use the same package name in **AndroidManifest.xml**, applicationId in **build.gradle** and don't forget to **Rebuild Your Project**.

Note:- I tried to change **np** to **jp**, so I selected ***np*** and I pressed **Shift + F6** for **Rename Refract** and renamed to ***jp***, it's ok to change others too.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you -
1) Open a file of your package.
2) Android Studio displays the breadcrumbs of the file, above the opened file.
On the package you want renamed: Right click > Refactor > Rename.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the easiest way to do this.

1. Create a new project with the desired package name
2. copy all files from old project to new project (all file in old.bad.oldpackage=>new.fine.newpackage, res=>res)
3. copy old build.graddle inside new build.graddle
4. copy old Manifest inside new Manifest
5. Backup or simply delete old project

Done!

Comment: that's not the most reliable way, simply refactoring does the job, imagine someone has more complex project, that has styles, dimens, drawables, libraries. This method takes a lot of time.

Comment: It's reliable if you follow my method step by step and it is very speedy if you follow them. 
Just forget about any complexity and consider you're creating a new project from existing source, then as I can see you don't know where drawable dimens libraries stays, I'll explain to you then you have to upvote my answer.
1- libraries are iside your build.graddle so if you backed up the file you would just have to copy the content inside the new build.graddle
2- drawables, dimens, styles are all inside the res folder. so if you have both projects new/old(package) opened u just have to drag/drop

Comment: Sometime refractoring is more complicated than you can imagine because I tried it without success then using my method every things worked like a charm

Comment: Yes Martin, agree this is also one way and it works. But it is not the fastest method. Thanks for detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not changed any package name. The following two steps worked for me. After doing the following, the application was installed as a NEW one , eventhough there was two applications with the same package name.

1) In the build.gradle

applicationId "mynew.mynewpackage.com"

2) In the AndroidManifest.xml
            android:authorities="mynew.mynewpackage.com.fileprovider"

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I moved my MainActivity file to the new package folder structure as prescribed... it refactored my AndroidManifest.xml. Finally after checking Logcat I realized that was the issue, and renamed it back to ".MainActivity" from ".MainActivity"

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 0):

Android studio's refactor-method messed up bad. So I did it manually and it worked great. Also really simple:

-Backup so you can revert if things go bad.

-In Android Studio: Open Replace In Files, and type the old package name to be replaced with the new, and git replace all.

-Close Android Studio.

-Manually rename the the directories in the app/src/main/java/... and app/src/test/java/... and app/src/androidTest/java/...

-Open Android Studio and Clean Project, Rebuild Project -> and done!