# Is it possible to change the company domain name in android studio after creating the project?

Tags: android

When I created android project in android studio, I found field Company Domain Name .I have created with some name first. Now I want to change that company domain  name. Is it possible to change? Please help me to solve this issue !

Comment: do you mean the package name like com.example.app etc?

Comment: Not the package name...while creating the project i found filed company domain name .

Comment: It was because of [applicationId "android.com"] was missing the gradle file.

Comment: Related posts - [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16804093/465053) & [Fully change package name including company domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18558077/465053)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can able to change the domain using following steps. For your example you are trying to change the domain name `com.example` to `com.example1`. So your package name should look like `com.example.application_name`.

1. Right click on the package name in the project explorer and then select `Refactor -> Move`.
2. A new popup will ask you to what kind of refactor you need to do. In that select the first one `Move package 'com.example.application_name' to another package.` and then click `ok`.
3. A new warning window will show that the package is in multiple places. Click `yes` on that warning.
4. A new dialog will opened. In that, change the `To package` value to the new domain name `com.example1` and then make sure the check box is enabled for `Search in comments and String` and `Search for text occurrences` and then click `Refactor`. Now a new dialog will open and ask a confirmation to create the new package. Click `Yes`.
5. In the bottom window it ll search all the named `com.example` and ask you to refactor. Click `Do Refactor` in that. That's it. you renamed the domain name from `com.example` to `com.example1`. The previous package will not be deleted. if you don't want that means you can delete it.

Comment: Great work ...thank you..it works fine...once you  have done this procedure..please follow this link to move further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: @VivekE: if this answer solved your issue, please accept it. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of it so that it turns green. This is how we thank people on _Stack Overflow_.

Comment: This was easier than I feared it would be. I had accidentally named the package "example.com" instead of "com.example" which made me feel very silly. Maybe it doesn't matter, but it's nice to have it fixed.