# how to change the package name: com.apps.example.name_app to com.example.name_app

Tags: android

I want to change my  package name: com.apps.example.name_app  to  com.example.name_app.

**edit:**

following the solution proposed by Mahendran Sakkarai in this post:
[Is it possible to change the company domain name in android studio after creating the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140432/is-it-possible-to-change-the-company-domain-name-in-android-studio-after-creatin)

all is well, but When I click rebuild button, or clean button, I get this error:
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGr3A.png)

**update:**

I knew later that this error has relation with the firebase,

the name on my google-services.json it should be same with my local.

To solve the problem:

1- I created a new project on firebase with the new Package name

2- I replaced the old google-services.json file with the new file provided by firebase

3- I clicked on "sync project with gradle files" .. and like that, my problem is solved

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details (what did not work for you for example) and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you want to change the app package id or the java source class package name?

Comment: Thank you for your help, my problem is solved, I updated my question

Comment: your package name .example keyword i think created problem with upload in apk in google play store