# How to change the Application name (android studio)

Tags: android-studio

At the top of my androidstudio Application bar it's written

```
(TreehouseParseWorkshop_FINAL1 - [~/Desktop/peaceKeeper]
```

I have used some code of Treehouse site, I just want to know how do I change "TreehouseParseWorkShop_FINAL1", been stock for nearly half an hour, could any of you help please thanks

Comment: try this link may help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/rename-full-android-package-name

Comment: this answer definitely will help u http://stackoverflow.com/a/20416699

Comment: did you mean the action bar ?? or package name??

Comment: package name, the one at the top of the android studio program?