# changed package name but old package name showing when installed the app on the android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I changed the package name of the application by following [How do I rename the android package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/rename-full-android-package-name)

However, the old package name is still being shown on the android device that the application is installed on:

```
    Android->Data->"old package name"
```

Comment: Did you right click on your project and select `Android Tools-> Rename Application Package`? If not, try that. Then I'd say do a clean and build.

Comment: @BinaryJudy: No such option on right clicking the project in android studio...

Comment: It just occurred to me that you may not have installed the Android SDK Tools. Go to the Android SDK manager, it's the button with an arrow facing down in the IDE, and there's a sections for "Tools". In that list is options to download and install the tools. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Android studio make sure you change applicationId in  the Build.gradle file