# How to Rename the Default Package of FBReader for Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android ebook reader using [FBReader](http://fbreader.org/FBReaderJ) and got stucked while renaming its package. After renaming the package, the app is not working. Can anybody please suggest the steps to rename the package of FBReader for android. Thanks in Advance

Comment: is your issue resolved? If yes then Please post answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before. [How do I rename the android package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name)

Change the package name manually in the manifest file.

OR

Click on your R.java class and the press F6 (Refactor->Move...). It will allow you to move the class to other package, and all references to that class will be updated.

Comment: I have done that but its not working. It contains C++ libraries and think that it needs to be compiled.

Comment: That's really something you should put on the question itself.