# Changing the package name

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali

I planned to change the package name through smali(reverse)

when I open up apktool.yml, I saw this

> *forced-package-id: '127'*

I have tried to change it but it crash
why should i do?

Comment: for changing package name  try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name

Comment: sorry but that post is about eclipse.. but I'm asking about smali

Comment: @SathishKumarJ Read the `Question` Properly and then comment. He has mentioned usnig `Smali` in `Question`.

Answer (score 36):

Assuming your goal is to rename the package name of the apk, the package names used for the classes are irrelevant. The package name of the apk is mostly unrelated to the package names of any classes in the apk. And there's no reason you need to touch the package id.

I would recommend unpacking the apk with apktool, and then edit the apktool.yml, setting renameManifestPackage to the new package name. Then when you rebuild the apk with apktool, it should use aapt's --rename-manifest-package functionality to change the package name.

After that, just resign the new apk and you should be good to go.

```
apktool d app.apk
// change "renameManifestPackage: null" in app/apktool.yml
// to "renameManifestPackage: my.new.package"
apktool b app -o new_app.apk
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/my.keystore new_app.apk mykeyname
```

And just to reiterate, you don't need to modify the package names of any classes.

Comment: I admit that your answer might be more helpful than mine. +1.

Comment: I have just changed package name in  apktool.yml but it didn't generated new apk

Comment: After using this method and signing, the app will not install

Comment: @cascading-style you probably need to delete the existing signature first. If you need more help, feel free to create a question. Make sure you include any errors from adb install, including any errors that show up in logcat during the install.

Comment: What about when the app contains a binary?

Comment: This worked for me: I had to get around a program blocking NewPipe, so I just changed the `renameManifestPackage` property from `null` to `org.duolabs.newpipe` and it allowed it to run. +1!

Comment: Can use [uber-apk-signer](https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer) to quickly sign the apk. Found it from this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40064149/8608146).

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge there are no fast ways to change the package name.
You have to change the `package="com.mycompany.myapp"` in ***Manifest.xml*** and then manually replace all the package name occurrences in smali files (and folders). Finally edit ***apktool.yml*** replacing the old package name, with your new package name.

A full detailed tutorial can be found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760965

Comment: there are also may be **custom views** so it's needed to change package names in xml

Answer (score 0):

I've tried different approaches but the most reliable for me has been the method described here:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-guide-mod-change-package-names-of-apks.2760965/

These are the steps:

1. Decode APK (using apktool)
2. Edit apktool.yml
3. Edit AndroidManifest.xml
4. Rename smali subfolders
5. Search & Replace *.smali (using Notepad++)
6. Build APK (using apktool)
7. Sign APK (using apksigner)

Tools needed:

- Apktool - https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/
- Notepad++ - https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/
- apksigner - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner

Download apktool and wrapper script to C:\apktool.

Let's assume you want to modify from/to as specified here:

From: **XVipreSettings.apk** (Package name: *com.xvipre.settings*)

To: **ModdedApp.apk** (Package name: *com.modded.app*)

**1. Decode APK (using apktool)**

```
apktool.bat d XVipreSettings.apk
```

**2. Edit apktool.yml**

```
apkFileName: XVipreSettings.apk
...
renameManifestPackage: null
```

is changed to:

```
apkFileName: ModdedApp.apk
...
renameManifestPackage: 'com.modded.app'
```

**3. Edit AndroidManifest.xml**

```
package="com.xvipre.settings"
```

is changed to:

```
package="com.modded.app"
```

**4. Rename smali subfolders**

```
move .\XVipreSettings\smali\com\xvipre\settings .\XVipreSettings\smali\com\xvipre\app
move .\XVipreSettings\smali\com\xvipre .\XVipreSettings\smali\com\modded
```

**5. Search & Replace *.smali**

- Start Notepad++
- Menu > Search > Find in Files... (Ctrl+Shift+F)
- Find what : *"Lcom/xvipre/settings"*
- Replace with : *"Lcom/modded/app"*
- Filters : "*.smali"
- Directory : "C:\apktool\XVipreSettings\smali\com"
- Press *Replace in Files* (may take a few minutes)

**6. Build APK**

```
apktool.bat b XVipreSettings -o ModdedApp.apk
```

**7. Sign APK**

(I'm assuming 31.0.0 here yours may be different, also if you don't want to sign using debug certificate you need to modify this step accordingly)

```
%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0\apksigner.bat sign --ks %homedrive%%homepath%\.android\debug.keystore --ks-pass pass:android --key-pass pass:android C:\apktool\ModdedApp.apk
```