# issue installing apk modified in apktool

Tags: android, apktool

I've been trying to change the package name for an android apk, but I've ran into some trouble.

I changed the package name as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812692), signed, and zipaligned it. However, whenever I try to `adb install modified.apk`, it gives me the following error:

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION]`

How can I fix this? I have already tried changing all of the references to the old package name in the AndroidManifest.xml, but that caused some of the references to xml files in `/res/` to break.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 12/15:

Still haven't figured this out and I can't find any documentation on this issue in the context of what I'm trying to do. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Uninstall previous Apk then install

Comment: @BineshKumar this is what I am trying to avoid. I am attempting to change the package name to allow both versions of the application to be installed.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file. I think your using GCM permissions. That's why its failed. Once you post your code i will post the answer.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yeGAqRP2

This is the unmodified manifest. To my understanding editing the apktool.yml and changing the `renameManifestPackage` value will change these for me. If this is not correct I'd love some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: @willi just change the permission in the manifest file for the apk in which you modified the package name.

Comment: @Hades this worked, thanks. I also had to change the authorities in the manifest to the new package name.