# Rename Package Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there is a lot of info on this here. But I can't find the answer to my particular question.

I'm trying to rename a package that is currently like this:

```
com.example.app.name
```

and I want to rename it to

```
com.example.name
```

I know you have to do refactor rename and make sure you have 'compact empty middle packages' turned off but I'm only know how to rename them when they are three directories long i.e. `com.example.name` and not how to actually get rid of one of the directories. So how do I reduce it from being 4 to only 3?

Hope I explained this correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename the android package name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name)

Comment: Assuming you don't have many classes, you could just move the files in the project view between the folders.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package), it's explained very nicely with pictures.

Comment: Instead of renaming package use build variant feature of android studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the package name in the manifest file. Make sure to hit the "Do Refactor" button in the Find window.

Also, you will need to edit the package name in the build.gradle file.

I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename Package Android Studio `com.example.app.name` to `com.example.name`

Steps:

1. Close/Unselect Compact Empty Middle Packag.
2. Move all source from "name" to "app".
3. Delete "name".
4. Change "app" to "name". :D