# Upload failed: You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted

Tags: android

When i try to upload my apk it gives the following error

You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

guys help me

Comment: I have changed but build is finished with error.If u have any solution help me

Answer (score 1):

just change the name of your package in Android Studio using refactor and it should work

Comment: where should i right click?

Comment: should we change com.example to com.navyasri?

Comment: help me i changed my package name com.example.personal.numbermania to com.navyasri.personal.numbermania in android manifest file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6600360/2995527

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16721566/2995527