# how to change activity name in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new in android studio. So I take a full project file from my friend. He told me just 3 changes you do and this app is fully your. Yes! he right I able to make a app with 3 changes with his project. But when I going to publish it in amazon it tell me that [snapshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLw42.png), 
[snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGwkx.png)

```
<activity
        android:name="com.smartsupport.youtuber.dharmendra.MainActivity"
```

how can I change this `"com.smartsupport.youtuber.dharmendra.MainActivity"` ?

My app name is Government Job's

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name

Comment: You need to change package name. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: sorry problem not solved

Comment: package name changed but still it tell the same thing. what should I do now?