# How to rename android package name: com.einee -> org.biggo.einee?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I seem to be having some issues with renaming as my app keep crashing when I try to run it. My app package name is com.einee and I want to rename it to org.biggo.einee

Comment: It seems a similar issue was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose `Hide Empty Middle Packages` in Project pane setting.
2. You click right directory `Refactor->Rename`.
3. Then, update `applicationId` in `build.gradle`
4. and then change package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
5. Clean and Rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is to rename the package name in the whole project using

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>