# How to Shorten Package Name?

Tags: android

I have imported a project in android studio now I want to change the package name and also shorten it.

This is the current package name:

`package com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdates;`

I want to rename it into:

`com.example.app`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Change the package name manually in the manifest file.
2. Click on your R.java class and the press F6 (Refactor->Move...). It will allow you to move the class to another package, and all references to that class will be updated

Reference: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name)

Comment: Cannot find R.java file